# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.parse.ParseObject cannot be cast to

Tags: android, classcastexception

I create 2 classes(`Meal`, `Restaurant`) which extend `ParseObject`, and create 2 custom adapters(`BottomFragmentMealAdapter`, `RestaurantAdapter`). I tried to do whatever I made in `BottomFragmentMealAdapter`(it works) for `RestaurantAdapter`. But it doesn't work.
Here is my log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: com.bogazici.menumizer, PID: 14739
>                                                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: com.parse.ParseObject cannot be cast to com.bogazici.menumizer.Restaurant
>                                                                               at com.bogazici.menumizer.RestaurantAdapter.getItemView(RestaurantAdapter.java:17)
>                                                                               at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.getView(ParseQueryAdapter.java:547)
>                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
>                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
>                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
>                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
>                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
>                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:581)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1034)
>                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:744)
>                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1180)
>                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:757)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
>                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
>                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
>                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
>                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
>                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zyg

Here is my `RestaurantAdapter`

```
public class RestaurantAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Restaurant> {
    //top line is 17
    private AlphaAnimation buttonClick;
    public RestaurantAdapter(Context context, final String filter_edit, final String filter_city, final String filter_region,0 final int filter_sort) {
       super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Restaurant>() {
           public ParseQuery<Restaurant> create() {
               // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to display
               // only top-rated meals.
               ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Restaurant");
               query.whereContains("city", filter_city);       
    if(!filter_region.equals("*Hepsi*")&&!filter_region.equals("*All*"))
                   query.whereContains("region",filter_region);
               if(filter_edit.equals("nothing")){
               }else{
                   query.whereStartsWith("restaurant", filter_edit);
               }
               switch(filter_sort){
                   case 0:
                       query.orderByAscending("averagePrice");
                       break;
                   case 1:
                       query.orderByDescending("averagePrice");
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       query.orderByAscending("restaurant");
                       break;
                   case 3:
                       query.orderByDescending("averagePoint");
                       break;
                   default:
                       query.orderByAscending("restaurant");
                       break;
               }
               return query;
           }
       });
    }
    @Override
    public View getItemView(Restaurant restaurant, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        //buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.8F);
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.restaurant_list_item, null);
        }
        super.getItemView(restaurant, v, parent);
        final String str_call = restaurant.getPhone();
        TextView locationTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_location);
        String str_location= restaurant.getRegion()+", "+restaurant.getCity();
        locationTextView.setText(str_location);
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_name);
        nameTextView.setText(restaurant.getName());
        TextView pointTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_point);
        String str_point = String.valueOf(restaurant.getAveragePoint());
        pointTextView.setText(str_point);
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_averageprice);
        String str_price = String.valueOf(restaurant.getAveragePrice())+" TL";
        priceTextView.setText(str_price);
        ImageView callImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_call);
        callImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View w) {
                // w.startAnimation(buttonClick);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+str_call));
                w.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        TextView mapText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_map);
        mapText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View w) {
                //w.startAnimation(buttonClick);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the right @ParseClassName("Restaurant) in your Restaurant class?

Comment: @ParseClassName("Restaurant")

public class Restaurant extends ParseObject {
    public Restaurant() {
    }
    public String getObjectId(){
        return getString("objectId");
    }
...

Answer (score 8):

you have to check two things

1. Ensure that your subclass has a `public default` (i.e. zero-argument) constructor. You must not modify any ParseObject fields in this constructor.
   and
2. Call `ParseObject.registerSubclass(YourClass.class)` in your Application constructor before calling `Parse.initialize()`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you registered your parse class in your application

Answer (score 0):

i think ParseQueryAdapter requires ParseObject as Generics and 'Restaurant' class is not of ParseObject type

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Adapter's getItemView()` method to look like -

```
 @Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject parseObject, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
}
```

Comment: @ParseClassName("Meal")
    public class Meal extends ParseObject{
    public Meal() {
    } // it works

@ParseClassName("Restaurant")
public class Restaurant extends ParseObject {
    public Restaurant() {
    } //doesn't work.